# spit items into different arrays and retrieving it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

this related to my previous question asked and thanks to every one here who is helping me to learn coding :D

i was previously working on an undo button which kind of works but not there yet :(

here is what i have done [click here](http://hybridimaginations.com/lambada/test.html). But the problem is since it goes step by step backwards it has to wait till the item where the previous color was applied in the same part. Is there a way i can split something like this [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/LdV4s/) will this idea work out?

here is the test html code:

```
  <div id="colour">
    <input type="submit" name="r1" id="r1" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="r2" id="r2" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" name="r3" id="r3" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" name="r4" id="r4" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" name="r5" id="r5" value="5" />
    <input type="submit" name="r6" id="r6" value="6" />
 </div>
 <div id="map">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="layer_a" value="a" />
    <label for="layer">layer_a</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="layer_b" value="b" />
    <label for="layer">layer_b</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="layer_c" value="c" />
    <label for="layer">layer_c</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="layer_d" value="d" />
    <label for="layer">layer_d</label>
 </div>
 <input name="selected" id="selected" type="hidden" value="" />

 <input type="submit" name="undo" id="undo" value="undo" />

 <div id="result"></div>
```

here is the test jQuery code:

```
 $("#colour input").click(function() {
    $("input[name='selected']").val(this.id);
 });
 var arraymap = [];
 var array_a = [];
 var array_b = [];
 var array_c = [];
 var array_d = [];

 $("#map input").click(function() {
    var mape = $(this).attr('id');
    var ccurrent = $("input[name='selected']").val();
    arraymap.push(mape);

    // trying to split it into diffrent arrays //
    if (mape == "layer_a") {
            array_a.push(ccurrent);
            var araycurrent = array_a;
    } else if (mape == "layer_b") {
            array_b.push(ccurrent);
            var araycurrent = array_b;
    } else if (mape == "layer_c") {
            array_c.push(ccurrent);
            var araycurrent = array_c;
    } else if (mape == "layer_d") {
            array_d.push(ccurrent);
            var araycurrent = array_d;
    };

    var mapid = arraymap[arraymap.length - 1];
    var colid = arraycurrent[arraycurrent.length - 1];

    var loca = mapid + colid;

    $("#result").append(mapid);
 });

 $("#undo").click(function() {
    arraymap.pop();
    var remover_map = arraymap[arraymap.length - 1];

    // trying get it back from split arrays //
    if (remover_map == "layer_a") {
            array_a.pop();
            var remover_col = array_a[array_a.length - 1];
    } else if (remover_map == "layer_b") {
            array_b.pop();
            var remover_col = array_b[array_b.length - 1];
    } else if (remover_map == "layer_c") {
            array_c.pop();
            var remover_col = array_b[array_c.length - 1];
    } else if (remover_map == "layer_d") {
            array_d.pop();
            var remover_col = array_a[array_d.length - 1];
    };

    var remove = remover_map + remover_col;

    $("#result").append(remove);

 });
```

Comment: I clicked on the *"**chick** here"* link hoping to find a sight for sore eyes. I was thoroughly disappointed. Shame on you for misleading me :p

Comment: @ShawnChin sorry for that buddy:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store you layer arrays in an object to use it as an associative array. That way you can easily reference them by the layer name.

Here's my version of your example: (Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qbdyp/)

```
var step_layer = [];  // layers affected by each step
var step_colour = {  // selected colours by layer
    "a": [],
    "b": [],
    "c": [],
    "d": []
};

var $map = $("#map"), $result = $("#result");  // cache
$("#colour > input").click(function() {
    var layer = $map.find("input[name='radio']:checked").val();  // current layer
    var colour = this.value;  // selected colour
    step_layer.push(layer);
    step_colour[layer].push(colour);
    $result.append("Added " + colour + " to layer " + layer + "<br/>");
});

$("#undo").click(function() {
    var layer = step_layer.pop();  // get most recently changed layer
    if (typeof layer === "undefined") {
        $result.append("(Nothing to undo)<br />");
        return;
    }
    var colour = step_colour[layer].pop();  // get latest change in that layer
    $result.append("Removed " + colour + " from layer " + layer + "<br/>");        
});
```

And here's a more elaborate example, one that's hopefully closer to what you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/uWUve/

Comment: Thanks!! before i tried to offset it with `.splice(-2,1)` and got a random effect to the end of the undo :P but ur a real  life saver.. once again Thanks!

Comment: Could you help me create a summary for your elaborate version? i want the colors to be present inside the boxes to be a summary. ie: if outer is green, mid and inner is red. the summary should be green and red.  what ever i try it just appends all the color i clicked rather than replacing it with the colors present in those 3 boxes. .[the link](http://jsfiddle.net/5JwY3/)

Comment: @SolomonSam I'm afraid I don't quite understand your requirements. Perhaps you could post another question with more details and examples? I'll have a look when I get a chance to, but more importantly, others may be able to help too.

Comment: @SolomonSam I had a few minutes to kill, so I fiddle with this. Is this what you mean when you say "create a summary" - http://jsfiddle.net/nvw63/ ?

Comment: that's exactly what i meant. thanks again! for spending your time on this